# what will be the updated Istio handler, instance and rule configuration

Tags: kubernetes, erlang, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, envoyproxy

The following istio configuration was being used in a legacy kuernetes cluster with old istio version to do the connection from microservices running in kubernetes an erlang virtual machine on websocket. I am working on a lift and shift of the microservices on an upgraded kubernetes cluster with the istio version 1.13.3 which does not support the istio handler, instance and rule resources. Can anyone please let me know how I can achieve the same functionality of the following configurations:

```
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: handler
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: dummy-blacklist
spec:
  compiledAdapter: listchecker
  params:
    overrides: ["X"]
    blacklist: true
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: instance
metadata:
  name: dummy-blacklist
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  compiledTemplate: listentry
  params:
    value: 'Y'
---
apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: rule
metadata:
  name: websocket-rewrite-header-rule
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  match: "true"
  actions:
  - handler: dummy-blacklist
    instances: [ dummy-blacklist ]
  requestHeaderOperations:
  - name: x-json-web-token
    values: 
    - (request.query_params["access_token"] | "")
```

I have already tried to use virtual service and envoy filter related configurations but not sure what exactly I am missing.
Please help so that I can fix the issue with websocket connection.